# find the curve $y = ax + bx^2$ that best fits the data using method of least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, curves, least-squares

There's a problem in curve fitting section,

Q) By the method of least squares, find the curve $y = ax + bx^2$ that best fits the following data.

```
x   1    2    3    4     5
y  1.8  5.1  8.9  14.1  19.8
```

I try to solve it by using  this fitting a straight line formula,

$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = na * b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$
$\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i = a\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$

I got $a = 3.56, b = 4.5$ which seems to be wrong? which formula should I use to solve this?

Comment: Your title and text do not agree.  There  $bx^w$ in the text and $b^2$ in the title.  Which is it?  For the title, $b^2$ is just a constant so you can call it $c$.  Otherwise you should use $b^2$ in your equations.

Comment: There may be a typo. Curve (straight line) is only $y=a +bx?$

Comment: @RossMillikan that was a typo. I'm sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Your equations are specific to fitting a straight line, which is not what you have.  There are more general forms for linear least squares fitting, where linear refers to the dependence on the parameters $a,b$, not the functions like $x, x^2$.  You are doing [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) but with the constant term forced to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i = a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 y_i = a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 +b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^4$$

This is derived by starting with an expression for the Sum of the Squared Errors

$$SSE = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$$
$$SSE = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - (ax_i+bx_i^2))^2$$

Take partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ and set each to $0$:

$$\frac{\partial SSE}{\partial a} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[2(y_i - (ax_i+bx_i^2))(-x_i)\right] \equiv 0$$
$$\frac{\partial SSE}{\partial b} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[2(y_i - (ax_i+bx_i^2))(-x_i^2)\right] \equiv 0$$

Then with some rearranging and simplification you get
$$-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i + a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 = 0$$
$$-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 y_i + a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 + b\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^4 = 0$$

Solving the equations gives you:
$$a = \frac{\sum x_i^4 \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i^3 \sum x_i^2 y_i}{\sum x_i^4 \sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i^3 \sum x_i^3}$$
$$b = \frac{\sum x_i^2 \sum x_i^2 y_i - \sum x_i^3 \sum x_i y_i}{\sum x_i^4 \sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i^3 \sum x_i^3}$$

Hope that helps

Comment: which is the correct formula? I tried to use the above formula but the a and b i'm getting is returning wrong estimate.

Comment: @user_12 What do you think the correct values are?

Comment: so I can use either formula for calculating right? How is the formula derived? I know how we can write the above answer formula but this one I'ven't seen before.

Answer (score 1):

In least square method for polynomials multiply both sides of equation  with $x_i$ and sum up.

Solve $(a,b)$ from:

$$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i = a\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^nx_i y_i = a\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3$$

$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3$ should be tabulated and summed in addition.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try it.

Comment: The best fit solution should plot convincingly through the center of  a "cloud" of the given data.

Comment: This answer is not correct. My solution gives `a=1.512857142` and `b=0.492857142`.

Comment: I gave it for $ y=ax+b,$ incorrectly.